# QGIS - Photo Widget

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

Is it possible to append info to the file name of a photo?  We use QGIS in office Merginmaps in the field to collect data.  When we setup the layers to collect utility pole data, we have added a photo of the utility pole.  Is there a way to add fields to the file name; My pole layer has default ID field and a pole #, could ID_POLE# be added to file name so in file directory you more easily understand what pic is for what point?

As I write this it get further complicated if multiple pics where taken for single point.  So I'm not sure now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet implemented, please follow https://github.com/lutraconsulting/input/issues/1595